# Optimizing Tab Control With AutoIT

Tags: performance, autoit

So I wrote this to simulate a program that would have a start and stop feature, and has a `tab design`. Right now there is a tab that has a `RichEdit` object intended to be a running log.

As you can see, after we "start" the program I put just some milliseconds of `sleep` to simulate running instructions. I created a function to check for requests that would be called on a larger scale randomly throughout code to ping the `GUI` per say.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiRichEdit.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global Const $h_numOfTabs = 2
Global Enum $H_TAB_1, $H_TAB_2, $H_TAB_END
Global $hGui, $h_logRichEdit, $iMsg,  $h_tabs, $h_startButton, $h_stopButton

Example()

Func Example()
    $hGui = GUICreate("Example (" & StringTrimRight(@ScriptName, StringLen(".exe")) & ")", 400, 550, -1, -1)

    ; ADD START AND STOP BUTTONS
    $h_startButton = GUICtrlCreateButton( "Start", 50, 450 )
    $h_stopButton = GUICtrlCreateButton( "Stop", 150, 450 )

    $h_tabs = GUICtrlCreateTab( 5, 5, 390,375 )

    ; LOG TAB
    GUICtrlCreateTabItem( "Log" )
    $h_logRichEdit = _GUICtrlRichEdit_Create ( $hGui, "", 8, 30, 384, 347, BitOR( $ES_MULTILINE, $WS_VSCROLL, $ES_AUTOVSCROLL, $ES_READONLY ) )

    ; STATS TAB
    GUICtrlCreateTabItem( "Stats" )

    ; Close TABS
    GUICtrlCreateTabItem( "" )

    GUISetState( @SW_SHOW ) ; initialize the gui

    While True
        CheckRequests()
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Example

Func Start()
    while true
        Sleep(100)
        CheckRequests()
    WEnd
EndFunc

Func Stop()

EndFunc

Func CheckRequests()
    $iMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    while $iMsg <> 0
        Select
            Case $iMsg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                _GUICtrlRichEdit_Destroy($h_logRichEdit) ; needed unless script crashes
                ; GUIDelete()   ; is OK too
                Exit
            Case $iMsg = $h_tabs
                Switch GUICtrlRead( $h_tabs )
                    Case $H_TAB_1
                        ControlShow( $hGui, "", $h_logRichEdit )
                    Case Else
                        ControlHide( $hGui, "", $h_logRichEdit )
                EndSwitch
            Case $iMsg = $h_startButton
                Start()
            Case $iMsg = $h_stopButton
                Stop()
        EndSelect
        $iMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

**At about 500ms sleep, the lag when switching tabs is visible.**

**My question:** On a larger scale, is this how we would handle/update things that are specific to a tab while running a larger program? If not, what would be a more efficient way of updating tab specific properties while running a larger overall program.

I have also seen a design recently where all the tabs and related components were their own `GUI's` but I am not sure the relevance of everything being its own `GUI` and if it pertains to this question.

Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated, I am new to AutoIT and trying to figure out some do's and dont's as well as efficiency.

Comment: I was looking at the reference for [GUICtrlCreateTab](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlCreateTab.htm) and it looks like they are creating a tab control that switched between GUI elements without using a gui message, so you might want to try that to avoid lag. However I tried it with a _GUICtrlRichEdit_Create() and it doesn't seem to work... The rich edit seems to appear no matter what tab is clicked on. It works with other GUI elements though like labels, buttons, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiRichEdit.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global Const $h_numOfTabs = 2
Global Enum $H_TAB_1, $H_TAB_2, $H_TAB_END
Global $hGui, $h_logRichEdit, $iMsg,  $h_tabs, $h_startButton, $h_stopButton

Example()

Func Example()
    $hGui = GUICreate("Example (" & StringTrimRight(@ScriptName, StringLen(".exe")) & ")", 400, 550, -1, -1)

    ; ADD START AND STOP BUTTONS
    $h_startButton = GUICtrlCreateButton( "Start", 50, 450 )
    $h_stopButton = GUICtrlCreateButton( "Stop", 150, 450 )

    $h_tabs = GUICtrlCreateTab( 5, 5, 390,375 )

    ; LOG TAB
    GUICtrlCreateTabItem( "Log" )
    $h_logRichEdit = _GUICtrlRichEdit_Create ( $hGui, "", 8, 30, 384, 347, BitOR( $ES_MULTILINE, $WS_VSCROLL, $ES_AUTOVSCROLL, $ES_READONLY ) )
    _GUICtrlRichEdit_AppendText($h_logRichEdit, "{\rtf {Showing \b1 Rich Text \b0}")

    ; STATS TAB
    GUICtrlCreateTabItem( "Stats" )

    ; Close TABS
    GUICtrlCreateTabItem( "" )

    ; Register Windows message.
    GUIRegisterMsg($WM_NOTIFY, 'WM_NOTIFY')

    GUISetState( @SW_SHOW ) ; initialize the gui

    GuiMessageLoop()
EndFunc

Func GuiMessageLoop()
    While 1
        $iMsg = GUIGetMsg()

        Switch $iMsg
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                _GUICtrlRichEdit_Destroy($h_logRichEdit) ; needed unless script crashes
                ; GUIDelete()   ; is OK too
                Exit

            Case $h_startButton
                Start()

            Case $h_stopButton
                Stop()
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
EndFunc

Func Start()
    ConsoleWrite('# Sleep' & @CRLF)
    Sleep(5000)
    ConsoleWrite('# Awake' & @CRLF)
EndFunc

Func Stop()

EndFunc

Func WM_NOTIFY($hWnd, $iMsg, $wParam, $lParam)
    Local $iLoWord = _WinAPI_LoWord($lParam)
    Local $iHiWord = _WinAPI_HiWord($lParam)
    ConsoleWrite('- WM_NOTIFY' & ' ' & $iLoWord & ' ' & $iHiWord & @CRLF)

    Switch GUICtrlRead( $h_tabs )
        Case $H_TAB_1
            ControlShow( $hGui, "", $h_logRichEdit )
        Case Else
            ControlHide( $hGui, "", $h_logRichEdit )
    EndSwitch

    Return $GUI_RUNDEFMSG
EndFunc
```

Try this example. It uses [GuiRegisterMessage](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUIRegisterMsg.htm) to capture
`WM_NOTIFY` Windows messages. `WM_NOTIFY` is not an ideal
message code for this, though have not found something
more suitable for only changing Tabs.

The code to hide and show the Rich Edit control has been
moved into the `WM_NOTIFY` function so that each time a
message is received, the Tab hide and show code executes.

[ConsoleWrite](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ConsoleWrite.htm) is used to show what the events of interest
are doing during testing. If your editor has a output
console pane, then you may be able to view the writes to
the console pane.

If an event such as function `Start` takes a long time,
then multi-processing may help to allow the Gui to
remain responsive with the message loop.

Want a <s>do</s> don't, avoid (*cyclic*) recursive function
calls and avoid getting trapped in loops.

---

Additional References:

- [Windows Message Codes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/WinMsgCodes.htm)
- [AutoIt Wiki about Tabs](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Tabs)